# Painting a Oval Component however the fill is overlapping the oval line, How do I fix this?

Tags: java, swing, awt, java-2d

My fill oval method is overlapping the line of the oval. How do I fill the oval without overlapping the line?

I have adjusted the heights and widths of both but can't seem to find the proper numbers to make it look just right.

```
public void paintComponent(java.awt.Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(lc);
    g.drawOval(0,0,getWidth()-1,getHeight()-1);
    g.setColor(fc);
    g.fillOval(0,0,getWidth()-1,getHeight()-1);
```

My results are a yellow filled oval with a red line around it. However, the red line looks like it is under parts of the yellow so it is not a clear red line that wraps all the way around the oval.

I want the line to be completely visible all the way around the oval.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe if you draw the filling first and then draw the contour?

```
public void paintComponent(java.awt.Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(fc);
    g.fillOval(0,0,getWidth()-1,getHeight()-1);
    g.setColor(lc);
    g.drawOval(0,0,getWidth()-1,getHeight()-1);
```

Then the contour should overlap the filling